# Overflowing navbar to a second row using Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm just getting started with Bootstrap, and am doing so by designed a page for myself from scratch. I'm still stuck on the navbar as of now.

Here's how I want it to work: On desktop/tablets, it should work just like conventional navbars, with one header element on the left and a list of option on the right. On mobile, however, instead of having the navbar collapse into a menu, I want it - all of it - to just move to another row within the navbar.

I tried making the class of the part I want to overflow to "sidebar", but the list still renders vertically, like with the collapse menu.

A friend of mine has implemented this on his site at "thepickletheory .com" (Can't add a direct link for lack of reputation), and it works really well there. He's just used a WordPress theme, however, and the code isn't in Bootstrap too, so I can't implement it myself either.

Here are some pictures that show what I'm trying to accomplish.

[Navbar in desktop/tablet view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqPw9.png)

[Name] --- [Item 1] [Item 2]

[Navbar in mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhtaV.png)

[Name]

[Item 1] [Item 2]

Here's the code for the navbar that I've written so far, which moves the second part of the navbar to another row, but renders the list vertically (links are dummies for now):

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Harshil Shah</a>
            </div>

            <div class="sidebar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Archive</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Would really appreciate some help with getting this to work. Thanks!

EDIT 2:

Through some rather fortunate trial-and-error, I've stumbled upon the solution: the unordered list just has to be assigned to the `.nav-pills` class, and that's all it takes.

Answer (score 0):

You has to specify `navbar-collapse` collapse here is used to enable the toggle menu in Small screens instead of showing full menu just look here

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"     data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Harshil Shah</a>
            </div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <div class="sidebar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Archive</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The responsive navbar requires the `collapse` plugin to be included in your version of Bootstrap don't mind which is binded in `bootstrap.js`. here the [**source**](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

Instead of collapse you can use bootstrap grid classes [**source**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed)

```
<div class="navbar-header col-xs-12 col-md-4">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
   <!-- here side bar menu -->
</div>
```

which will bind accordingly by device you are using. put col size as your need.

Comment: That's actually the opposite I wanna do: I want the navbar to not collapse, but rather shift to another row on mobile devices. This is how I want it to appear on [desktop](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FqPw9.png) and on [mobile](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UhtaV.png).

Comment: I tried using the grid system too, but even this renders the second part of the navbar vertically.

Comment: you need to show the navbar same as in Desktop and mobile ah?